# How to enable GridView sorting by the code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

I have a `GridView` filled in code behind from `DataTable`, I want to enable sorting when clicking on a header cell.
If any help would be very appreciated

Comment: i see that you are new to asp.net.. does your grid have paging?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Is there a specific issue you are running into?

Answer (score 0):

Add `AllowSorting="True"` in the GridView Properties

Answer (score 0):

set AllowSorting="True",give an OnSorting Event, and handle that event accordingly.
[Heres a sample](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1598-how-to-sort-the-gridview-data-in-aspnet.aspx)